# What is the Stationary Diffusion Equation Intuitively?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm having a little trouble understanding what the stationary diffusion equation does. As I understand it, the standard heat equation is $u_t = -k\Delta u$, where $k$ is for conductivity.

My intuitive understanding of this is that the heat equation is describing a process going towards equilibrium described by Laplace's equation. ie. the heat equation describes something headed towards a system described by Laplace's equation.

The diffusion equation is a little more general $u_t = -\nabla \cdot (g \nabla u)$ and I assume that it works in the same way the heat equation does, but with some function g in the mix. I don't understand what $g$ is doing in this equation, but what I'm really confused about is the stationary version of this. ie $f = -\nabla \cdot (g\nabla u)$. What does this describe? Is is an equilibrium state? If so, what does $g$ contribute? Otherwise it's just Poisson's equation, no?

I have heard something about $g$ being chosen discretely from a distribution, what does this refer to? Quick explanations or references (using only very elementary physics if any) are appreciated.

Apologies beforehand if this seems exceptionally naive.

Comment: What you have described as the standard heat equation should be $$u_{t} = \color{red}{+}k \Delta u$$ The stationary diffusion equation would be $$- \nabla \cdot (g \nabla u) = 0$$ The $g$ is just a nonconstant diffusion coefficient (or matrix, if $u = (u_{1},u_{2},\dots)$).

Comment: Thank you, but what does the diffusion coefficient mean? I've been trying to figure it out but have yet to get a clear answer.

Comment: The diffusion coefficient $k$ tells you how fast the quantity $u$ diffuses; the larger the value, the faster it diffuses. Take the 1D problem on a bounded domain $$u_{t}=k u_{xx}$$ The solution via separation of variables $$u=\sum_{n}\phi_{n}(\lambda x)e^{-k\lambda_{n}^{2}t}$$ with $\phi_{n}$ the spatial eigenfunctions satisfying $\phi''=-\lambda^{2}\phi$, $\lambda_{n}$ the eigenvalues. Looking at the $e^{-k\lambda^{2}t}$ term, we can see that if $k_{1}<k_{2} \implies e^{-k_{2}\lambda^{2}t}< e^{-k_{1}\lambda^{2}t}$ and so $u$ goes to $0$ _faster_ for larger $k$ i.e $u$ diffuses more quickly.

Comment: Note that $k$ (or $g$) can be constant _or_ dependent on the variables of the system. If $k = k(x)$ i.e the diffusion is varying in space, it just tells you that in some regions of the domain, $u$ is diffusing at a _different_ rate to other regions.